# Fire event on scrolling an open bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, debugging, jquery-events

I am using "Bootstrap" modal (actually a branch of it that disables background scrolling when the modal is shown and adds more features - "bootstrap-modalmanager").

I need to do something when the modal is being scrolled. The problem is I can't find what is actually being scrolled.

When I use Chrome dev tools I can see in the time-line the event "scroll" is bring fired but I can't find where to see the div it scrolls, which I need to know so that I can do:

this:

```
 $(window).on('scroll',"THE ID I AM LOOKING FOR",function(){..})
```

or this:

```
 $("THE ID I AM LOOKING FOR").on('scroll',function(){..})
```

Answer (score -2):

You can look for the target element in the event object. This will tell you where the event was fired.

```
$(document).on('scroll', function(e) {
    e.target; //e.target will be the DOM element where the scroll event was fired
});
```

You can pass a different jQuery selector to the 'on' event according to your requirements.

Comment: Yes, but how do I break on this? the $(document).on('scroll'...) is not fired when the modal is opened.
I am trying to understand how I find what fires the event.

Comment: So, you want to find what element fires the modal 'open'?

Comment: The document's scroll event doesn't fire when the modal popup is scrolled.